# Gradle issues SDK location not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I cannot figure what is happening here with this error message Im getting can anyone help plese.

I'm usimg Androind Studio 4.2.1 and not allowed to update the gradel at all!

[image]

Comment: What do you see in Menu: File>Settings and after Appearence & Behaviour > Android SDK?

Comment: I have manage to get ride of that error but got this error now Unrecognized Android Studio (or Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA) version '202.7660.26.42.7351085', please retry with version 2020.3.1 or newer.